# Mounting Volume in DockerFile on Windows

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am working on a Springboot project with docker. I tried to mount volume so I could have access to generated files from the Springboot application in my local directory. The data is generated in the docker container but I can not find it the local directory.

I have read many topics but none seems to be helpful.

Please, I am still new to docker and would appreciate suggestions to assist.

I have tried to mount the volume directly in the dockerfile as there is a docker compose file to run the service alongside others. Below is what I have in my Dockerfile and docker-compose

##### Dockerfile

```
FROM iron/java:1.8
EXPOSE 8080

ENV USER_NAME myprofile
ENV APP_HOME /home/$USER_NAME/app
#Test Script>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
#Modifiable
ENV SQL_SCRIPT $APP_HOME/SCRIPTS_TO_RUN
ENV SQL_OUTPUT_FILE $SQL_SCRIPT/data
ENV NO_OF_USERS 3
ENV RANGE_OF_SKILLS "1-4"
ENV HOST_PATH C:"/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/path/logs"
#>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
RUN adduser -S $USER_NAME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $SQL_SCRIPT
RUN chown $USER_NAME $SQL_SCRIPT
VOLUME $HOST_PATH: $SQL_SCRIPT
ADD myprofile-*.jar $APP_HOME/myprofile.jar
RUN chown $USER_NAME $APP_HOME/myprofile.jar

USER $USER_NAME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
RUN sh -c 'touch myprofile.jar'

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c","java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar myprofile.jar -o $SQL_OUTPUT_FILE -n $NO_OF_USERS -r $RANGE_OF_SKILLS"]
```

##### Docker-compose

```
myprofile-backend:
  extra_hosts:
    - remotehost
  container_name: samplecontainer-name
  image: sampleimagename
  links:
    - rabbitmq
    - db:redis
  expose:
    - "8080"
  ports:
    - "8082:8080"
  volumes:
    - ./logs/:/tmp/logs
    - ./logs/:/app
```

Comment: Add a tree command output to help you with the mount structure

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are mounting the same folder `./logs` twice. Docker-compose volume mount syntax is `- <your-host-path>:<your-container-path>`. Also, its better to use relative paths when you are building the application. So change docker-compose file to (assuming you want to see the files in `./target` relative to the Dockerfile:

```
myprofile-backend:
  extra_hosts:
    - remotehost
  container_name: samplecontainer-name
  image: sampleimagename
  links:
    - rabbitmq
    - db:redis
  expose:
    - "8080"
  ports:
    - "8082:8080"
  volumes:
    - ./logs/:/tmp/logs
    - ./target/:/app
```